# modifying main query to query for ranges e.g. from 1999 to 2016

Tags: query, advanced-taxonomy-queries, tax-query

I've taxonomy `_year` and I'm modifying main query by hooking into `pre_get_posts` action.

My code looks like this:

```
        if ( ! empty( $_GET['mt-from-year'] ) ) {

            $from_year = sanitize_title_for_query( $_GET['mt-from-year'] );

            if ( ! empty( $_GET['mt-to-year'] ) ) {

                $to_year = sanitize_title_for_query( $_GET['mt-to-year'] );

                $query->set( $post_type . '_year', range( $from_year, $to_year )  );

            } else {

                $query->set( $post_type . '_year', range( $from_year, date('Y') ) );

            }

        }
```

Now this works fine. But I want to create a `_price` taxonomy, obviously `range( 0, 10000000 );` could become a problem performance wise, and also hit the memory limit.

so my question is three fold:

1. Would you leave `_year` as is? since ranges are relatively small e.g. `1900 - 2016`
2. In case of `_price` would you still go with range? or implement a different query?
3. ditch taxonomy for `_price` and use `postmeta` - problem here is that metas are not well optimized in WP, so I'd have to add index to `value` col.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terms are *grouping* mechanism. Query logic for them is mostly limited to matching or not matching, which makes you use huge arrays of many possible values in your case.

While year is passably a group (might or might not make sense) the price is most definitely not. Would you shop in store where items are organized in isle by price? Isle with all $1 items, isle with all $2 items, and so on?

Discreet individual values are firmly realm of post meta. Meta also allows much more flexible queries, such as `BETWEEN` for your use case.

I am not sure why do you consider it "not well optimized", but it would certainly be better place to start for range queries than terms.

Comment: taxonomy columns have indexes, meta columns don't. hence they will be inherently slow to query for. I will need to add indexes to those columns.

Comment: but you helped me a lot, I had a feeling I was going off road with taxonomies just because received more love by wp devs.